# Donwloading files from Firebase to Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have stored some doc files in a folder "Colleges_names" in Firebase storage. I want to download them in my android app. When I click the required button to download file nothing happens.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://du-admissions-app.appspot.com");
    StorageReference  islandRef = storageRef.child("COLLEGES-NAMES").child("CLG_BA(ENGLISH).docx");

    File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "file_name");
    if(!rootPath.exists()) {
        rootPath.mkdirs();
    }

    final File localFile = new File(rootPath,"CLG_BA(ENGLISH).docx");

    islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file created  created " +localFile.toString());
            //  updateDb(timestamp,localFile.toString(),position);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file not created  created " +exception.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please upload logcat output. Try to change the URL reference to an http one, it is usually just below the gs address

Comment: already tried that..btw thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve those files with their extension, you should upload your files programmatically first, get the `downloadUrl()` of the file uploaded and then retrieve that `downloadUrl()` and being the download of the files.

I would recommend you to [read this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files).

Comment: thanks ..but in my app user don't need to upload any file..they just have to download